# Find current file path in Swift with Linux

Tags: swift, linux

Simple googling would lead me to the code:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.defaultManager()

// Get current directory path

let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
print(path)
```

However, defeaultManager seems not to be accessible in Linux.

- How can I find the current path using either Foundation or Glib in swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code is for Swift 3. Here is the code for swift 4:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

// Get current directory path

let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
print(path)
```

Comment: `FileManager.defaultManager()` is for Swift 2 not Swift 3